# Google Sheets Regexreplace - remove numbers, double quotes, "X" and "x" from strings

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a listing of products that include sizes, in a variety of formats.
I need to separate them into 2 columns, 1 with the sizes, the other with the names.
So, for example, "12"x10" Large Widget" becomes [12" x 10"] [Large Widget].

I'm trying to use REGEXREPLACE to remove the numbers, but can't seem to find a combined syntax that will handle "any number, double quotes, the letter X lowercase and capital" in a single expression.

And then I'd need to do the reverse, in other words, extract JUST the numbers and double quotes and X/x, for the other column.

Can't just use SPLIT or RIGHT/LEFT, because the position of the intended split will differ from line to line. Can't "Split Text To Columns", because there are occasional double quotes in the item names too.

So I'm thinking, Step 1: filter out just the numbers and double quotes, Step 2: filter out just the names.

In other words:

```
Input: [14" x 17" Large Widget]
Output (2 columns): [14" x 17"] [Large Widget]

Input: [7"x2" Small Gadget]
Output (2 columns): [7"x2"] [Small Gadget]
```

I understand how REGEXREPLACE works, just need help with the syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.+"") (.+)")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Well, I'll be damned.